# creation of gates in fcm

Tags: python

I am working on the fcm and I want to create gates for .fcs files.
I have seen the examples in docs but I do not understand how to create the manual gates.

can anyone tell me how to create manual gates when user will select the points manually? (for example polygate, freegate, etc)

Answer (score 0):

are you asking about the fcm library at http://code.google.com/p/py-fcm/

If so, there isn't a specific way to get the points of a gate. As a back-end library we've felt that falls more into a graphics tool kit's territory.  We've provided an example in the gui/mpl_gate.py file in the src tree as one way using matplot lib.